# Dense rank for decimal values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I calculate the danse_rank for a decimal values.

I have input values like:
pid| biosver|
1  | 1.01
1  | 1.04
1  | 1.11
1  | 01.32
1  | 1.09
1  | 1.03
1  | 1.29

Expected Output:
pid| biosver|Rank
1  | 01.32  |1
1  | 1.29   |2
1  | 1.11   |3
1  | 1.09   |4
like this.....

Comment: The column has String datatype

Answer (score 0):

Use **`window`** `dense_rank()` function for this case.

**Example:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

//sample dataframe
val df=Seq((1,1.01),(1,01.32),(1,1.29),(1,1.03)).toDF("pid","biosver")

val w= Window.orderBy(desc("biosver"))

//if your datatype is string then use casting
val w= Window.orderBy(col("biosver").cast("decimal(10,2)").desc)

df.withColumn("Rank",dense_rank().over(w)).show()

//+---+-------+----+
//|pid|biosver|Rank|
//+---+-------+----+
//|  1|   1.32|   1|
//|  1|   1.29|   2|
//|  1|   1.03|   3|
//|  1|   1.01|   4|
//+---+-------+----+
```

Comment: If the column has data like 01.03.32, 1.00,89, 01.04.90.
How to calculate the rank?